# In CERT Office-ID(PCC) test , book and ticket with Remark failed due to "Transaction failure | Either invalid GTID or not logged in"

Tags: travelport-api

**Our queries to Travelport support team:**

In the OfficeID (OID or PCC) Booking and Ticketing API scenario, when we try to book with a remark, it throws an error ("Transaction failure | Either invalid GTID or not logged in"). We found the below solutions in the travelport form, so as per the link reference solution, it will happen on the CERT test and it will work in production because our Office-ID is already valid in production. We don't know if this is the same issue or not, so please advise what reason this error throws.

Answer (score 0):

**Travelport Response:**

> Host sign on for the pcc - OfficeID  is dropped and this may cause issue.
> I have send a request for approval to developer admin's email. Will
> recreate the sign on once this is approved

As suggested by Travelport support team, They anticipate that our admin developer will approve the host sign of OID (PCC). This issue will be resolved once our admin developer approves it.